# Iterating through JSON data using the map function

Tags: arrays, json, loops

Here is the app working with the one dimensional data set:
https://boiling-coast-12353.herokuapp.com/

I wrote code that made clickable buttons for each country in my data. But now I need to use a data set structured differently so I can transform the data.
My data set is now like this:

```
{ 
    "2010": [
        { "Country": "Argentina", "Percentage": 10.44 },
        { "Country": "Bolivia", "Percentage": 51.62 },
         ...
    ],
    "2011": [
        { "Country": "Argentina", "Percentage": 10.34 },
        { "Country": "Bolivia", "Percentage": 51.62 },
          ...
    ],
      ....
}
```

Im trying to generate a button for each country, but the code I used before no longer works:

```
{
        this.state.data.map((data, index) => (
          <button key={index}className="button-primary" onClick={() => {this.onChooseCountry(index);
          }}><span className="btn-content" tabindex="-1">
          </span>{data.Country}</button>
         ))
        }
```

Comment: What is it framework/libary? Is it react ?

Comment: Looks like you have an object so you should use `Object.keys` or something similar

Comment: be specific about your query. if possible tell where your code is breaking or what your trying to achieve. Do you just want country names or do you want year and country names in a button?

Comment: Yes framework is react. Just a button for the country name. here is the app using the simple data set. 

https://boiling-coast-12353.herokuapp.com/

The drop down menu has no function, so I am trying to transform the data via the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have actually done is changes your data from an array to JSON Object. Here is the following code on how to iterate through a nested JSON array of your structure:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
  var json = {
                "2010":[{ "Country": "Argentina", "Percentage": 10.44 },
                        { "Country": "Bolivia", "Percentage": 51.62 }],     
                "2011":[{ "Country": "Argentina", "Percentage": 10.44 },
                        { "Country": "Bolivia", "Percentage": 51.62 }]
               };
    return <div> {Object.keys(json).map(year => json[year].map(data => <button> {year} | {data["Country"]}</button>))} </div>
  }
}
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, 
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice this looks good I've been giving it a try. The only thing is I've imported my JSON data using fetch, so I don't know what to do with var arr = [];
I was able to add let arr = [];  after the main render function and before return without error, but Im a little unclear where the Object.keys function should reside, and the divs for the buttons. Im now getting a lot of 'data is not defined errors'. I also changed json to data because thats what it's called in my initial state.

https://boiling-coast-12353.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I was able to console log the object keys though using 
console.log('Object Keys: ', Object.keys(result));
as setState in my componentDidMount() is data:result,
so that's a step in the right direction!

Comment: @NicolHawkins It was my mistake that I didn't dry run my code. I have updated my answer with the proper snippet. Please check.

Comment: @NicolHawkins Did you try the solution?

Comment: Thanks for checking in! I actually ended up using this to get the buttons generated:

{this.state.data[this.state.year] ?
  this.state.data[this.state.year].map((info, index) => (
  <button key={index} className="btn-primary" onClick={() => this.onChooseCountry(info, index)}>
            {console.log('info is here', info)}
            {info.Country}
            </button>
          )) : "NO DATA"
        }
        </div>

Comment: Just now, I was able to get yours to work by using this.state.data in place of json. I will play around with it more, because it might be useful as Im having trouble both displaying divs conditionally and transforming the data at the same time, so this gives me more to play around with. Thanks again!